# What's the word for this part of a sailing ship?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes on sailing ships or in primitive mills, torque is supplied by several people walking around a big wheel, each pushing an attached lever. Or the lever might be pulled by a donkey. What do you call this kind of wheel? You sometimes see them in movies like pirates of the Caribbean.

Comment: Windlass, capstan, or winch, depending on which feature you're focusing on.

Comment: @HotLicks Could you expand this into an answer, in particular pointing out the distinction between the terms, and which features go with which?

Comment: I'm not really up on marine terminology enough to give an authoritative answer.  A capstan is a vertical-axis thingie (as pictured by ratchet freak).  A windlass is usually horizontal-axis.  A winch is a bit more generic.  There are issues as to whether the rope is collected on the device or simply wrapped around it a few turns (as pictured) -- a winch most certainly collects the rope, a capstan hardly ever.

Answer (score 22):

[Capstan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capstan_(nautical))

[image]

> a broad revolving cylinder with a vertical axis used for winding a rope or cable, powered by a motor or pushed round by levers.

[Google]

Answer (score 0):

A winch.  Sometimes a grinder which is really short for a grinder winch.  More modern ships tend to use either mechanical or standing grinder winches known as coffee grinders.